# When is a family of sets said to be non-empty?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Is a family of sets said to be non-empty if it has some member other than ths empty set ? Or if the empty set is a member of a family of sets, is the family non-empty?

(Note that the empty set might not always be a member of a family of sets. For example, if for a given set $A$, we take the family of all sets $B$ such that $A \subset A \cup B$, then the empty set will not be a part of this collection.)

Answer (score 2):

A family of sets is said to be non-empty if it has any member at all (it is irrelevant whether the member is the empty set).  The only family of sets that is not non-empty is the family that has no members.  In particular, the family of sets whose only member is the empty set is non-empty.

Answer (score 2):

A family of sets is nonempty as long as there is at least one set in that family. It does not matter if the set that is in the family is the empty set or not. (Note that the set containing the empty set is a nonempty set. It contains one element, namely, the empty set).

Answer (score 1):

A family of sets is just a function $I \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$. Its said to be non-empty iff $I$ is non-empty. This means that if $I$ is a non-empty set and $f : I \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ is the constant function that assigns to each element of $I$ the set $\emptyset$, then $f$ is **non**-empty.

Comment: "Family of sets" is also frequently used to just mean "set of sets", which I'm guessing is the context OP is asking about.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I think that's a misuse of the term, but you may be right. I would call that a *collection* of sets.